# ONVIF: Authentication failure with SNC-CH110 using ONVIF protocol

Tags: authentication, camera, video-streaming, ip, onvif

I've camera SNC-CH110 from Sony. Default user is 'admin' and password is 'admin' too. My big problem is with authentication.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    <SOAP-ENV:Code>
        <SOAP-ENV:Value>SOAP-ENV:Sender</SOAP-ENV:Value>
        <SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
            <SOAP-ENV:Value>ter:NotAuthorized</SOAP-ENV:Value>
        </SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
    </SOAP-ENV:Code>
    <SOAP-ENV:Reason>
        <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">Sender not Authorized</SOAP-ENV:Text>
    </SOAP-ENV:Reason>
    <SOAP-ENV:Detail>
        <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">The action requested requires authorization and the sender is not authorized
        </SOAP-ENV:Text>
    </SOAP-ENV:Detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

According to ONVIF specification 1.02, I use “user name token profile” for authentication which is described in specification http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf or in http://www.onvif.org/Portals/0/documents/WhitePapers/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer%27s_Guide.pdf

Below is the Script that I use to form soap request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header> 
        <Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken> 
                <Username>admin</Username>
                <wsse:Password Type=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wssusername-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"">" + hashBase64 + @"</wsse:Password> 
                <wsse:Nonce >" + Convert.ToBase64String(_nonce) + @"</wsse:Nonce> 
                <Created>" + dt + @"</Created> 
            </UsernameToken> 
        </Security> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
        <tds:GetCapabilities> 
            <tds:Category>All</tds:Category> 
        </tds:GetCapabilities> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

Here is my code for sending request:

```
byte[] _nonce = new byte[16];
RandomNumberGenerator rndGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rndGenerator.GetBytes(_nonce);

// get other operands to the right format
string dt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");
byte[] time = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dt);
byte[] pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin");
byte[] operand = new byte[_nonce.Length + time.Length + pwd.Length];
Array.Copy(_nonce, operand, _nonce.Length);
Array.Copy(time, 0, operand, _nonce.Length, time.Length);
Array.Copy(pwd, 0, operand, _nonce.Length + time.Length, pwd.Length);

// create the hash
SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
string hashBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(operand));

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("../../../xml/GetCapabilities.xml");
Communication.SendTcpXml(xml.InnerXml, new Uri("http://192.168.1.25/onvif/device_service"));
```

I'm really confused, because I can't find a mistake. It's very interesting that when I use date, password, nonce and username from program ONVIF Device Manager (I took it via Wireshark), I'm successful. BUT I don't understand how this program hash password, because I'm doing it exactly according the specification and when I use same date, nonce and password I can't get same hashed password like this program. I will be grateful for any help, thank.

Comment: I made a little Java function a while ago to compute and show the Header part (just a little test). I tested the result using SoapUI and a Hikvision camera and worked perfectly; I hope it helps: http://pastebin.com/x16Prr2J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash computation looks like correctly, but I found that element "Created" has wrong namespace, it should be in wsu namespace.
It is also will be more correctly to define attribute EncodingType for Nonce element with value `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary` in your case.

Comment: Hi, thx for respond. About namespaces, you're right. I corrected it some time ago. But it wasn't real problem. It sends ws-usernametoken right. But I've just slightly changed code and it's generate hash like that program that I mentioned above, so correct. I'm right now busy, but when I will be free, I will find that catch and I will write it here what was problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you synchronize clocks between you and the camera?
You should first call the `getSystemDateAndTime`, record your local time, and after that, use the diff between the two when sending further requests.

`getSystemDateAndTime` does not require authentication, so you're clear at that point.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the dif between the two" calls when sending future requests?? Aren't they supposed to be both using UTC??

I know I'm late, but I'd really like an answer! (:

Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Hi, I mean that since this is a camera, it is most likely that its clock is not adjusted correctly. So in order to authenticate, you need to first read its clock using `getSystemDateAndTime`, then you compare it with your clock, and calculate the time difference. The next queries you send the camera should take into account this time difference. So you should call `currentTimeMillis` (I'm assuming Java here) and offset the result by the above time difference.

Comment: Look at this example (see what I do with clientTime and serverTime)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798419/build-soap-web-service-client-using-wsdl-documents-in-eclipse/10394687#10394687